# cowplot: extracting subplot after calling plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, grob

I am using `plot_grid` to arrange two plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), g=sample(c('a', 'b'), 100, replace=T))
p1 = ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=g))
p2 = ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=y, y=x, colour=g))
p = plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow=1)
```

Question: Is there a way to extract the individual ggplot objects *after* calling plot_grid? For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
q = extract_ggplot_objects(p)
q1 = q[[1]]
q2 = q[[2]]
q1 = q1 + theme(legend.position='none')
q2 = q2 + ylab('') + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
new_p = plot_grid(q1, q2, nrow=1)
```

I know that for this specific example, it is easiest to just remove the legend from p1 before calling plot_grid. However, the problem I'm trying to solve is much more complicated and it would be helpful if there were a general way of doing this.

Comment: why not just use p1 and p2?

Comment: The actual problem is much more complicated, but I chose a simple example just to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: `plot_grid()` converts the ggplot objects into grid graphics objects (grobs). Once that has happened, you can't go back. It might be best to store your plots in a list, manipulate a you see fit, and then hand to `plot_grid()` as the final step.

Comment: Thanks. It is amazingly difficult to edit grobs :(