# Add geom_point() to cowplot subplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, geom-point

I have made a cowplot using

```
gg <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

I now want to add a `ggplot2::geom_point()` layer to `p1` but I only have access to `gg`. How can I pull `p1` and `p2` back out, add a layer to `p1` and then make a new cowplot, `cowplot::plot_grid(p1_new, p2)`?

I tried

```
cowplot::plot_grid(ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  gg$layers[[1]]$setup_layer + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)), 
  ggplot2::ggplot() + gg$layers[[2]])
```

but that does not work. I don't really understand how `ggplot2` (and `cowplot`) store the plots, grobs, layers, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, as it would be better to have `p1` and `p2` in a list, so that you can edit them before calling `plot_grid`. See comment by Claus at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472415/cowplot-extracting-subplot-after-calling-plot-grid

Comment: @AndrewGB Thanks! I was trying to avoid the list solution. Also, I could not find that question you linked when I was searching--so this is a duplicate I think. :(